# Executing a parent function from child doesn't update the parent's properties

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular 2 you work a lot with `this`, which is fine but I've found that it also creates an issue when you want to pass down a function down the component hierarchy.

Take this for example:

```
export class ParentComponent {

  myFunctionFromParent() {
    this.isActive = true;
  }
}
```

Then we pass this function down to a child:

```
<parent>
  <child [onClick]="myFunctionFromParent"></child>
</parent>
```

And let's say `child` is a simple button:

```
<button (click)="onClick()"></button>
```

Now, when `myFunctionFromParent` runs, `this` should be the `ParentComponent` but it's not.

Instead it's the `ChildComponent` that will have it's `this.isActive` property changed.

This creates a lot of issues as you can't execute parent functions from a child component and expect the parent properties to change.

Passing down functions works as you would expect them to do in Angular 1, but now it seems broken.

Is this no longer the way to do things like this? What is the correct way to to this in Angular 2?

Comment: FYI....you can access parent's function from child component.

Comment: have you heard of `Injector`? using Injector you can inject parent component into child and then child can call any parent's function.

Comment: @micronyks You're right, I did see an answer like that.. But when creating abstract components it's not the best method however. In specific scenarios then I guess it would be. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing functions around use default Angular data binding with inputs and outputs:

```
class ParentComponent {
  myFunctionFromParent() {
    this.isActive = true;
  }  
}
```

```
class ChildComponent {
  @Output() onClick = new EventEmitter();
}
```

```
<parent>
  <child (onClick)="myFunctionFromParent()"></child>
</parent>
```

```
<button (click)="onClick.emit()"></button>
```

Comment: So calling emit on a function reference executes it?

Comment: Calling `emit()` on an `EventEmitter` emits an event you can subscribe to with `(emitterName)="doSomething()".

Comment: Ok, but shouldn't it be like @ThierryTemplier did it then? Turning `(onClick)="myFunctionFromParent"` into `(onClick)="myFunctionFromParent()"`?

Comment: Right, forgot to change that.

Comment: You and Thierry basically have the same answer, but he was a bit faster so accepting his. Thanks for your explanation though :)

Comment: Turned out that this was the working one, `[onClick]` doesn't work, it has to be `(onClick)`.

Comment: Thanks, glad to hear it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use this instead:

```
<parent>
  <child (onClick)="myFunctionFromParent()"></child>
</parent>
```

and define an `@Output` in the child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <button (click)="onClick()"></button>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output('onClick')
  eventHandler:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  onClick() {
    this.eventHandler.emit();
  }
}
```

Comment: What would the output return? Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Hmm.. Not sure I understand what's happening here. Isn't `myFunctionFromParent` being called instantly rather than when I click the button?

Comment: In fact, `onClick` must be a custom event for the `child` component. To implement a custom event, you need to have an `@Output` in the component (associated with a property of type `EventEmitter`). To trigger the event, you need to call its `emit` method. In this case, the expression you register in the parent component against the event will be executed.

Comment: The `onClick` event isn't a native event so you need to handle it by yourself

Comment: Interesting, that does make things a lot simpler. Will have some changes to do in my components then, cheers :)