# How to make an object property function into an eventemitter?

Tags: javascript, angular

This is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542624/executing-a-parent-function-from-child-doesnt-update-the-parents-properties) question that was about function references between components.

If I have a `ParentComponent`:

```
export class ParentComponent {
  public myParentVariable = 'Hello world';

  test() {
    console.log(this.myParentVariable);
  }

  public options: any[] = [
    {label: 'Item 1', onClick: this.test},
    {label: 'Item 3', onClick: this.test},
    {label: 'Item 6', onClick: this.test},
    {label: 'Item 2', onClick: this.test}
  ];
}
```

As you can see I pass a reference to `test` in the `onClick` property.

Then I have a `ChildComponent` which I pass `options` to from the `ParentComponent`:

```
<child [options]="options"></child>
```

And in `child` I have a list:

```
<ul class="dropdown-list">
  <li *ngFor="#option of options" (click)="option.onClick()"></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see in the template I then call `onClick` from before as `(click)="option.onClick()"`.

The problem now is that from here it has no idea what `this.myParentVariable` is anymore since we're just passing a reference to `test`. So instead I want to make `onClick` into an `EventEmitter` which I can then call `.emit()` on, so that we execute `test` with the correct data binding, like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542624/executing-a-parent-function-from-child-doesnt-update-the-parents-properties).

But since I pass down an array containing objects that contains a property that reference a function, I'm not quite sure how to make the single `onClick` property of each object an `EventEmitter`.

I tried making the entire `options` into an outputted `EventEmitter` but that failed miserably.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: You could use bind method of the function: onClick: this.test.bind(this)

Comment: @kemsky Well I'll be damned, it worked. Is this angular 2 specific or TypeScript? Also provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**this** keyword in JavaScript depends on context. In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is called. Since TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript it behaves the same, please follow the links below.

> ECMAScript 5 introduced Function.prototype.bind. Calling f.bind(someObject) creates a new function with the same body and scope as f, but where this occurs in the original function, in the new function it is permanently bound to the first argument of bind, regardless of how the function is being used.

[function's this keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#The_bind_method)

You could also use arrow functions as alternative.

Answer (score 2):

By passing parent functions to the child, you are tightly coupling the parent component to the child (which is normally not recommended).  In other words, you are revealing information about parent methods to the child.  Ideally, the child should not know anything about the parent.  (This makes the (child) component more reusable.)

Instead of your current approach, i.e., instead of passing down parent function references to the child, pass down some IDs or some other unique values.  When a click event occurs in the child, pass the ID or unique value back up to the parent (using an output property/EventEmitter):

```
<li *ngFor="#option of options" (click)="myEmitter.emit(option.uniqueValue)"></li>
```

Then in the parent, map that value to the appropriate function call and call it:

```
<child [options]="options" (myEmitter)="doWork($event)"></child>
```

```
doWork(uniqueValue) {
   // map uniqueValue to some function and call it
}
```

Another added benefit with this approach is that you won't have to mess with `this` contexts.

Comment: Although this is one solution, it seems a bit more messy then just calling `.bind(this)` on the referenced function like @kemsky's answer. However, I like the idea and I will keep this in mind in other scenarios, but for this particular one I don't think it's going to work the way I want it to. But thanks :)